# SQL query to count all children forum topics and posts

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to organize posts into simple forum structure. Each post has title, description, post_id and parent_post_id. Posts with parent_post_id=-1 are root top-level forums.

```
Forum 1
  - Topic 1
    - Post 1
    - Post 2
Forum 2
  - Topic 2
    - Post 3
    - Post 4
```

How to count all nested posts for Forum 1, Forum 2 etc?

So far I have the following query

```
select forum.title, count(comment.post_id) as count from post as forum
  left outer join post as topic on topic.parent_post_id = forum.post_id
  left outer join post as comment on comment.parent_post_id = topic.post_id
  where forum.parent_post_id = -1
  group by forum.title
```

but it returns wrong results.

Comment: Remove the `GROUP BY` and select the columns you want.  Your query doesn't have much relationship to the results you specify.  It would help if you specified your desired results as a result set with fixed columns and rows.

Comment: Then Mysql says "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation ... incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by"

Comment: Could be the wrong result because you are using **left join**

Comment: @ymakux . . . The query in your question would not generate that error.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
select forum.title, count(comment.post_id) as count from (select * from post where parent_post_id = -1) as forum
  left outer join post as topic on topic.parent_post_id = forum.post_id
  left outer join post as comment on comment.parent_post_id = topic.post_id
  group by forum.title
```